# Splatoon 2 salmon run do you have to be in the same rank as your friends in order to play with them?

Tags: splatoon-2

I was trying to start a room with a friend of mine but every time we did, we just kept getting this "unable to connect to friend" notif. Whether i join him or he joins me. Our connection is good too so I have no idea what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a lower connection than needed to connect. If you have a high enough connection, then, you do have to have the same rank.

Answer (score 0):

no you do not need to be the same rank as your friend,
However there are a few drawbacks to it when you or your friend is lower then the other,
Such as the one with the highest rank will get Reduced EXP (it warns u before u join a friend in salmon run about this) and that u might not have much of a challenge beating the wave

if u cant connect with your friend this might be the reasons

- your friend is already ingame
- connection problems midway (not form your switch but between you and him or the server)